# Requesting for a bounty from someone?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, etiquette

I have a java web app question which seems to be impossible to resolve. Its not getting
much attention. If I get no answer within 24 hours, then I would like to put a bounty on
it. Unfortunately, I don't have the points. Can I request someone to set a large bounty on
this?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more patient. You asked the question just *2 hours* ago. Stack Overflow doesn't guarantee lightning-quick answers. Maybe *after* some time passes, you can consider the bounty.

Comment: @user3580294 - but I have no points to offer.

Comment: @james then answer some questions and then get some

Comment: @SamIam - that could take a while.

Comment: You gotta wait 48h until placing a bounty on a fresh question. Time enough to answer a couple dozen questions and earn 50, 100 or 200 points.

Comment: Let me know if you need a bounty. But make sure your question is **on-topic**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know a friend that could offer a bounty, sure, ask them (assuming you don't start voting for each other). At 20 reputation, you can also get into chat where you might be able to ask about it and maybe run across someone who might be willing to offer a bounty (I wouldn't explicitly ask for a bounty, though). If you mean coming to Meta and posting a question solely in the hope of finding someone that will add a bounty to your question - no, that would not be on-topic here and would be deleted quickly.

If you really want the reputation to offer as a bounty, your best course of action is just earning it yourself by posting good questions and answers, or even suggesting quality edits. Why rely on other people to give up their reputation for you?

Comment: others might want to give up a tiny amount of rep if thy think that the question is nice for them too